# Physical disconnection from network and intermittent socket error 10057

Tags: sockets, winsock

A customer of mine has a Windows application where there is a network connection between two machines. The system is supposed to cope with the connection being lost. It does this by keeping a counter on the client position which is reset every time data is received from the server. If the counter reaches 60 seconds (i.e. we haven't heard from the server for 60 seconds) it performs some expected action to cope with the connection being lost.

The customer has a problem, however, where sometimes the connection will be lost but the client doesn't perform the expected action. Upon investigation, it appears that this is an intermittent problem caused by the client's socket to the server sometimes raising error 10057 (WSAENOTCONN / "Socket is not connected") when the connection is lost. Because the client behaves differently when it gets a socket error the customer doesn't get the desired behaviour when they get this socket error. This is not difficult for me to fix, but I am a bit puzzled by the different behaviour.

To reproduce the problem I'm physically pulling the network cable out of the back of my server machine. The majority of the time, the effect on the client side is that we just don't get any data over the socket, and we don't get an error. Some fraction of the time however error 10057 is raised. Can anyone shed any light on why there is this inconsistency? The client socket is a nonblocking STREAM socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect you would get an error only if you try to send something.  That is when the TCP connection would discover it can't reach the other end point.  This will take a variable amount of time to discover the failure, depending on the network round trip time.  There might be a "keep alive" option, that forces the socket to periodically send something to detect failure even when app is idle.

Comment: You were right: the error happens when we do a 'send' on a socket that hasn't connected. The customer uses a 3rd party socket-wrapping class that calls 'connect', but then sets an internal flag to 'connected' before it gets the WSAAsyncSelect callback - so we don't really know if we're connected yet. Someone wasn't aware of this nuance, and took 'connected' in the third-party socket class to mean that the socket was in fact connected. There's then a bit of a race condition to see if the socket connects before we next do a send. Where it's still not connected, the send causes the 10057 error.

Comment: You can get WSAENOTCONN from most any Winsock API, not just send().

Comment: @EJP, yes, any API might signal the error, but the non-connected state can only be discovered if TCP tries to send something, whether application data or internally generated keep alive.

Answer (score 1):

`WSAENOTCONN` is a bug in your application. It isn't a result of a lost connection. The result of a lost connection is `WSAECONNRESET.` Your code must have got `WSAECONNRESET,` and then proceed to use the connection as though it was still valid. *Then* you get `WSAENOTCONN.`

Comment: Thanks, it is a bug in the application as you say - see my comment for user1055568 below. I don't actually get WSAECONNRESET but it looks like we're just doing 'send' on a socket that's not connect.